# How to unproxy child objects from org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository descendant

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, lazy-loading

I have created a many-to-many relationship of users to projects in a MySQL database and have used hbm2java (the hibernate tool to generate java classes from the data base tables). Since I'm using the gradle plugin org.hibernate.gradle.tools.Schema I don't have a hibernate.cfg.xml.

I can fetch and correctly print the list of users from my descendant of `CrudRepository<User,Long>` (see my code below) and each user object has a `getProjects()` function. When I try to iterate the projects owned by the user, I get this error:

`org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.xyz.dbmodel.orm.User.projects, could not initialize proxy - no Session`

I want to stick with the  default lazy loading approach used by java code generated by hbm2java.

I've tried calling `Hibernate.Initialize(user.getProjects())` (as discussed at https://howtodoinjava.com/hibernate/use-hibernate-initialize-to-initialize-proxycollection/) but I still get the same error when I try to do

```
for(Project project : user.getProjects()) {... }
```

All the examples I could find seamed to assume I could execute the above for loop and unproxy each project. I cannot.

Here is my repository:

```
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import com.xyz.dataservice.dbmodel.orm.User;
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {}
```

Here I create the repository:

```
@Autowired com.xyz.repository.UserRepository userRepository;
```

Here I successfully fetch the list of users

```
Iterable<User> users = userRepository.findAll();
for(User user : users) {
   log.info("User="+user.getName()); // this works!
   Set<Project> projects = user.getProjects();
   for(Project p : projects) // Error happens here!
   {
      log.info("  project="+p.getName());
   }
 }
```

The expected results are that I get a list of projects for each user.
The actual results are the exception `org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException`.

Thank you!

## Feb 02 2019 Morning Update

Regarding Hibernate Configuration

I'm not sure what you mean. My gradle plugin is generating this hibernate.cfg.xml file:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration 
     SYSTEM "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
 <hibernate-configuration>
   <session-factory>
     <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</property>
     <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
     <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306</property>
     <property name="hibernate.connection.username">searchapp_user</property>
     <property name="hibernate.connection.password">secret</property>
     <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
     <property name="hibernate.connection.zeroDateTimeBehavior">convertToNull</property>
   </session-factory>
 </hibernate-configuration>
```

…

Adding Transactional

I have added  `org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional` to the new function I am calling

```
@Transactional
public int fetchUsers() {
    Iterable<User> users = userRepository.findAll();
    return listUsers(users, "");
}
```

When this did not help, I tried enhancing my repository with the Transactional attribute:

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {
  @Transactional
  public List<User> findAll();
}
```

Shucks, this did not help either.
I did notice this strange entry in the acres of log entries. What does it mean?

```
 2019-02-01 10:50:42.285  INFO 5096 --- [  restartedMain] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$6c9c1be1] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
```

Thanks again!

## Feb 02 2019 Afternoon Update

Oops, I forgot to check that link concerning the tranasactional documenation.

I'm not sure how to use @Bean and @Transactional on the same function.

Can you show me an example?

The @Bean examples I've seen return a lambda that is then called mysteriously later. Do I need the lambda to be declared transactional? Is that possible? If not, do I need to replace the lambda with a descendant of java.util.function.Consumer<> whose accept function is declared with @Transactional?

## Feb 05 2019 Update: Solution Found!

I was using the new Java8 lambda syntax and I had to abandon it in favor of the older inner class syntax so I could declere the function @Transactional.

```
  @Transactional
  class InitSpecialCommandLineRunner implements org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner{
      @Transactional // this is important!
      @Override
      public void run(String[] args) {
          int count = listProjectsForEachUser(); // this works!
      }
  }


  @org.springframework.context.annotation.Profile("initialize")
  @org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean
  @Transactional
  public org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner initSpecial() {
       return new InitSpecialCommandLineRunner(); // this works

  // How to declare this transactional?
  //  return args ->
  //  {
  //      int count = fetchUsers();
  //      Iterable<User> users;
  //  };
```

}

I hope this will help someone else some day.

Comment: What's your Hibernate configuration. Looks like your session is getting closed straight after the repository call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the transactions only span the immediate call to the repository.

To fix this put a `@Transactional` annotation on the method that should define your transaction scope. 
At least the method that hosts the code you showed us.

That method needs to be public and on a Spring bean.
See https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html for details.